# One Router/Access Point and multiple SSIDs?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-access-point

> **Related question:**
>   [Two SSIDs on one router](https://superuser.com/questions/373175/two-ssids-on-one-router)

I understand some routers allow you to setup multiple SSIDs. Do you need to make any special arrangements (besides creating the different security congiruations on the router software)?

Do you have to assign these SSIDs to different channels on the router? If you dont, does this make them less secure?

Last thing I want to do is set up a less secure wireless network!

Comment: On consumer routers it's most common to use a second SSID for a guest network that has internet access but limited or no access to your local network. Can also use a lower security setting on this guest network to let old devices work while also limiting their access to your home network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a router allows for more than one SSID then you probably don't need to do anything "special" (all functionality and setup should be standard with the router).

According to [WesleyDavid](https://superuser.com/users/6580/wesleydavid) in a comment posted to [this](https://superuser.com/a/373179/81403) question, "multiple SSIDs can exist on the same radio / channel and each network is separate".

Having two SSIDs on the same channel would not affect security.

Answer (score 0):

You're halving the effectiveness of each wireless network if one network card is having to switch between broadcasting/receiving on two different channels/SSID's. Think of it like having two computers fighting for bandwidth on a single wireless network - the router can only provide so much. Might want to consider a dual band router that has independent wireless networks so the second one would not effect the primary.